# Cannot provision Control Tower Account Factory SC Product via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-service-catalog, aws-control-tower

We want to use Terraform to provision the Control Tower Account Factory Service Catalog product using the TF resource aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product via its name, however because Control Tower controls this products and creates two versions/artifacts of this product (1 active, 1 inactive) upon update we receive an error:

│ Error: error provisioning Service Catalog Product: InvalidParametersException: Multiple Provisioning Artifact with name AWS Control Tower Account Factory found.

So this means that we cannot release an update of this product and be able to dynamically provision it using its name via Terraform.

Does anyone know how we might be able to make it work?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-control_tower_account_factory.

Comment: Thanks Marko, yes we saw